# Python Behave BDD framework -Step Definition Jumper

Tags: python-behave

Do we have some alternative plugin for python behave for jumping from feature file to step definition.I know Behave BDD Support is available in professional edition.
So do we have something to achieve jumping feature in pycharm community edition or any other tool.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no alternative to PyCharm Professional edition. I tried XCode with different plugins, but they provide only syntax highlighting. Community edition also provide syntax highlighting without jumping feature.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for Win, Linux, and Mac, and nice extension, which allows to have code-navigation from feature file by CTRL+Clicking a step to its step definition. The extension is [Cucumber (Gherkin) Full Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexkrechik.cucumberautocomplete). I have just pushed a [small behave project](https://github.com/bv/vscode-behave) for checking the extension settings.

- Install Visual Studio Code
- Install the extension for Visual Studio Code
- Clone the project and check the navigation from `features/one.feature` file to `features/steps/definitions.py`
- use the `.vscode/settings.json` for your project

The extension also allows to have snippets as you type.

Comment: looks like i can't get this to work in macOS ... works fine on centos

Answer (score 0):

you can use the cucumber plugin in vscode check [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexkrechik.cucumberautocomplete). And after installing the plugin create a .vscode folder in the root of the project and add settings.json file similar to below one.

```
{
    "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
        "features/**/*.py"
    ],
     "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "features/*feature",
    "cucumberautocomplete.gherkinDefinitionPart": "@(given|when|then|step)\\(",
    "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": false,
    "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinValidation": false,
}
```

And you project structure for this

root > features > (Inside you can maintain both steps and feature files)